# How do i make an arraylist in one class point to the same arraylist in another class? Java

Tags: java, arraylist

How do i make an arraylist in one class point to the same arraylist in another class without having to make a new arraylist or object?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the arraylist in constructor of another class.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a reference of the ArrayList from one class to another. This can be done through a method parameter such as a setter method or a constructor parameter.

e.g.,

Class1.java

```
public Class1 {
  private ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
  private Class2 class2 = new Class2();

  public Class1() {
    myArrayList.add("foo");
    myArrayList.add("bar");
    class2.setMyArrayList(myArrayList);
}
```

Class2.java

```
public Class2 {
  private ArrayList<String> myArrayList;

  public void setMyArrayList(ArrayList<String> myArrayList) {
    this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
  }
}
```